# How can I send all the metrics, etc cpu, memory, network, of a host together with MetricBeats?

Tags: metricbeat

My system need to push to a monitor service the status (cpu load, memory, disk, memory, ...) of some  hosts collected by MetricBeats. But I found all these metrics will be collected and sent asynchronously,  I need to put them together by myself and it might probably  not be the real situation. Is there any way to send all these info in just one message?

```
 - module: system
  metricsets:
    # CPU stats
    - cpu

    # System Load stats
    - load

    # Per CPU core stats
    - core

    # IO stats
    #- diskio

    # Per filesystem stats
    - filesystem

    # File system summary stats
    - fsstat

    # Memory stats
    - memory

    # Network stats
    - network

    # Per process stats
    #- process

    # Sockets (linux only)
    #- socket
  enabled: true
  period: 10s
#  processes: ['.*']
```